# Derivation of the state equation of a van der Waals gas. Can I invert the derivative to help me?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus, gas

> The state equation of a van der Waals gas is
> $$\left(P+\frac{a}{v^2}\right)(v-b)=RT$$
> with $a,b$ and $R$ constant. Find $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\bigg\rvert_P.$$

Finding $\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\big\rvert_P$ is very tricky and I don't know how to do it. But can I instead find $\frac{\partial T}{\partial v}\big\rvert_P$, which is a lot easier, and invert it? Or that’s not a valid manipulation and I must find $\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\big\rvert_P$ the hard way? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Partial derivatives do not invert at all.

Comment: @VincentThacker What do you mean? The method is indeed valid.

Comment: [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: Why not just use implicit differentiation?  If you just take the derivative with respect to T of both sides, you'll get an equation that is *linear* in $\partial v/\partial T$, so it's easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on need and desire, the chain rule can be useful.

$$-1 = \left( \frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\right)_Z\ \left( \frac{\partial X}{\partial Z}\right)_Y\ \left( \frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}\right)_X $$

Substitute for example $Z = p$, $Y = T$, and $X = V$. The two derivatives that are easiest are $\partial p$ with respect to $T$ or $V$. Rearrangements will give what you want.

Note that any term $\partial Z$ will be a function of its two opposing variables $(X, Y)$. As such, when the analysis requires that you state $\partial V / \partial T$ as a function of only $(p, T)$, your attempt to invert as $\partial T / \partial V$ will not work. The chain rule will not directly provide what you need but may allow easier mathematical manipulations.

Comment: So I can make $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\rvert_P=-1/(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\rvert_v+\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}\rvert_T)$$ and those differentials are easier to calculate. Is that correct?

Comment: Your expression is incorrect -- products not summations. Review the chain rule in partial derivatives from a textbook or on-line source. Substitute terms appropriately.